# Build failed while running build.xml

Tags: eclipse

I am running my build.xml as 1 Ant Build .

I have jdk and jre  1.7.0_80 installed on the machine; this is the console log :

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\Alessandro\workspace\cqwebapp\build.xml

clean:
      [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\Alessandro\workspace\cqwebapp\build

init:
       [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Alessandro\workspace\cqwebapp\build
       [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Alessandro\workspace\cqwebapp\build\classes

compile:
       [javac] Compiling 85 source files to C:\Users\Alessandro\workspace\cqwebapp\build\classes
       [javac] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.7.0_80). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
       [javac] java.lang.NullPointerException
       [javac]  at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Paths.getPathEntries(Paths.java:215)
       [javac]  at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Paths.getPathEntries(Paths.java:200)
       [javac]  at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Paths.computeBootClassPath(Paths.java:389)
       [javac]  at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Paths.lazy(Paths.java:166)
       [javac]  at com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.getLocation(JavacFileManager.java:857)
       [javac]  at com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.hasLocation(JavacFileManager.java:674)
       [javac]  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.initProcessorIterator(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:224)
       [javac]  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:188)
       [javac]  at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.initProcessAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:992)
       [javac]  at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:821)
       [javac]  at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
       [javac]  at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
       [javac]  at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:342)
       [javac]  at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:333)
       [javac]  at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:76)
       [javac]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       [javac]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       [javac]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       [javac]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       [javac]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:57)
       [javac]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1160)
       [javac]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:936)
       [javac]  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
       [javac]  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
       [javac]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       [javac]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       [javac]  at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
       [javac]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
       [javac]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
       [javac]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
       [javac]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
       [javac]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
       [javac]  at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
       [javac]  at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:36)
       [javac]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
       [javac]  at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:705)
       [javac]  at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:527)
       [javac]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       [javac]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       [javac]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       [javac]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       [javac]  at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:371)
       [javac]  at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.launchConfigurations.AntLaunchDelegate$1.run(AntLaunchDelegate.java:269)
       [javac]  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Alessandro\workspace\cqwebapp\build.xml:36: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 546 milliseconds
```

Those images are :

1. The jdk1.7.0_80 folder ( gained by installing the corrispective
   jdk.exe from Oracle Website)
2. The JRE
3. the current Compiler selected
4. Build Path pt1
5. Build Path pt2

[image][image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: The error relates to the path.  Line 215 calls path.length() which is causing the NPE.  Is the path defined?

Comment: How can I check if the path is correct

Comment: Can you show the build path settings in the IDE? How is it configured?

Comment: I will add it in the question body

Comment: Thanks.  Looks ok.  Also check the ANT script (build.xml) and what paths are being sent to the compiler.